# Query multiple collections from Shopify in GatsbyJS

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I want to display groups of Shopify products based on what collections they're associated with, using [gatsby-source-shopify](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-shopify/)

Filtering to get all products from one collection as easy as running this query:

```
  const { allShopifyCollection } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        allShopifyCollection(filter: {id: {in: "Shopify__Collection__Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN0aW9uLzE3NzAxMjY3MDQ5OA=="}}) {
          edges {
            node {
              products {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
    `
  )
```

However it's not possible (to my knowledge) to query multiple times on the same data type in the same component.

What's the preferred way to approach this issue?

- Use multiple components that fetches the data for each collection and
  pass it to a grid component?
- Fetch all collections and filter out each collection?
- Another solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use [query aliases](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases)?

```
const { allShopifyCollection } = useStaticQuery(
  graphql`
    query {
      collection1: allShopifyCollection(filter: {id: {in: "Shopify__Collection__Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN0aW9uLzE3NzAxMjY3MDQ5OA=="}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            products {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }

      collection2: allShopifyCollection(filter: {id: {in: "Shopify__Collection__someOtherCollection"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            products {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }

      collection3: allShopifyCollection(filter: {id: {in: "Shopify__Collection__yetAnotherCollection"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            products {
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
  `
)
```

Comment: Ah! I was not aware that this was possible. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped.